# FlexSlider Images Displaying

Tags: html, css, flexslider

Trying to get images to display on a webpage however they will not unless I remove the `<li style= background-image>`, and replace with `<img src="image.jpg">` I get the dots associated with Nav, but only a white page. I was following a tutorial on codepen, which got me this far. Any help would be appreciated.

DEFAULT.HTML

```
<!-- Place somewhere in the <head> of your document -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="flexslider.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js">    </script>
<script src="jquery.flexslider.js"></script>

<div class="flexslider-container">
<div class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
      <li style="background-image: url(http://placehold.it/1600x900/F3D92E/FFFFFF);"></li>
      <li style="background-image: url(http://placehold.it/1600x900/D0021B/FFFFFF);"></li>
      <li style="background-image: url(http://placehold.it/1600x900/4A4A4A/FFFFFF);"></li> 
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
<script>
$(window).load(function() {
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: true,
   directionNav: true
  });
</script>
});
```

Default.CSS

```
.flexslider .slides > li {
  background-position: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
   }

.flexslider-container,
.flexslider .slides,
.flex-viewport {
  height: 100%;
   }

html,
background-image {
 height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  }

body {
  position: relative;
 margin: 0;
padding: 0;
  }

ul.slides {
 margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
  }

  .flexslider {
   margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 border: 0px;
 #overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: body also needs a height of 100%

Comment: So by adding to body
`height: 100%;` Should resolve the issue? When I tried this didnt seem to work out.